# Python abs() function failing on negative number

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.6, absolute-value

I'm working in python3.6 on linux and came across a pretty obvious failure of the abs() function. My variable `x` ended up as a very large negative number (possibly `-inf`), but the absolute value `abs()` function still returned a *negative* number, which shouldn't be possible. I put in a quick fix for my code by just adding 0.1 to the input of `abs()` but.... am I misunderstanding how `abs()` should be used?

```
$> x
-9223372036854775808

$> abs(x)
-9223372036854775808

$> np.abs(x)
-9223372036854775808

$> abs(x+.1)
9.223372036854776e+18

$> np.abs(x+.1)
9.223372036854776e+18
```

EDIT: Solved below, but it boils down to `x` being a `numpy.int64` and not just `int`, unbeknownst to me.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Python 3.6.3 on MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: I also tried to reproduce it using `x= -9223372036854775808` then `abs(x)` and it produced a positive result

Comment: Please specify the shell you're using and the Python version.
This does not reproduce with Python 3.8 or 2.7, either command-line execution of a program or IDLE shell.

Comment: Works fine for me with python 3.8.5 and ipython in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: `print(x, type(x))`  shows what?

Comment: also `type(abs)`

Comment: You should clarify - is `x` a Python int or a `numpy` array?  If array, what `dtype`?

Comment: `$> print(x, type(x))` gives `-9223372036854775808 <class 'numpy.int64'>`

Thanks, this is it. It was a numpy.int64, which explains it all, as @ShadowRanger pointed out below

Comment: This is an interesting corner case, and I'd like to upvote the question, but I'd feel better about it if you could explicitly show how to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @jk_sri: [Editing your question to add the answer to the question itself is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216722/322040). In this case, you added nothing new, so I just rolled the "answer in question" part of the edit back; in the future, if you discover a better answer, even as a result of reading an existing answer, please post it as an answer, don't edit the answer into the question. If an existing answer answered your question well, up-vote it; if it solved your problem completely and is "better" (by your criteria) than any other answer, click the check box to accept it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thanks for the info, still new using stackexchange. upvoted your wonderful detective work of course

Answer (score 8):

You didn't think to mention it (I inferred it from your tests with `np.abs`), but it's important that `x` is a `numpy.int64` (or equivalent signed 64 bit type). That specific value, in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), has no positive equivalent, so `abs` just produces the same value again (it *could* be made to raise an exception, but `numpy` stuck with the low level C behavior where it returns the original value in this case).

Convert it to a true Python `int` first, e.g. `abs(int(x))` and it will work.

---

Explanation of why it works this way:

The bit pattern of `-9223372036854775808` is `0x8000_0000_0000_0000` (highest bit only is set, underscores for readability). Two's complement negation is handled algorithmically by flipping all the bits and then adding one, with carry, so the conversion changes `0x8000_0000_0000_0000` to `0x7fff_ffff_ffff_ffff` (all bits flipped), then adds `1`, which carries the whole length of the field (since every bit but the high bit is set), producing `0x8000_0000_0000_0000` again. That same bit pattern does actually correspond to the bit pattern an unsigned 64 bit quantity equal to `9223372036854775808` would have, but given it's interpreted as signed, it continues to be interpreted as the most negative value, not one higher than the most positive value `int64` value (which can't be represented as an `int64`).

Comment: This does feel like a python bug to me, not very Zen

Comment: @Chris_Rands: It's not Python, it's `numpy`; Python `abs` trusts the `__abs__` method of the type to return the correct value (it can't know it's really an integer and that the return value is logically wrong). And `numpy` is rather more "bare metal, performance at all costs" than core Python (which isn't that, at all); checking literally every mathematical operation for overflow in a case like this, where `2**64 - 1` values don't need it, and one *maybe* does (heavy number crunching code sometimes *wants* silent overflow), slows things down for minimal benefit (if any).

Comment: @paradox: Not one of the downvoters, but I get it; the OP neglected to tell us that `x` was a `numpy` type. While my psychic debugging powers are awesome, and in this case, I was pretty much 100% sure they were on target (I'd have restricted myself to a comment if I wasn't), questions that omit critical details (like the libraries used and the definitions of variables) aren't providing a [MCVE], and are arguably "bad".

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes. I agree with you that OP should have done better to give us the right context.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers! Sorry, I didn't even realize `x` was a `numpy.int64` and not just an `int`. I'll edit the original post to reflect this